# CSS gradient not working on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, css

I have created a [gradient background](http://www.display-inline.fr/projects/css-gradient/#startType=hex&startValue=FFAD26&endType=hex&endValue=FF7701&step1Type=hex&step1Value=FEA026&step1Position=50&step2Type=hex&step2Value=FFFFFF&step2Position=50&step3Type=hex&step3Value=FFFFFF&step3Position=50&step4Type=hex&step4Value=FFFFFF&step4Position=50&step5Type=hex&step5Value=FF8B00&step5Position=50&size=210&extOpera=1&extIE=1) using a CSS generator. This works perfectly in all major browsers and on Android. However in iOS i get [this](http://piclair.com/data/trwm6.jpg).

What do I need to add to this gradient in order to make it working on iOS?

**Edit:** Because this question isn't gaining enough attention, I'd like to ask a different question: What do I need for css tag to create a linear gradient for safari/ios, when, as in this case, -webkit-linear-gradient is not working? Are there any other css gradient tags, specifically for safari?

Here's the code for my background:

```
.gradient {
/* Legacy browsers */
background: #FF7701 url("gradient-bg.png") repeat-x top;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
/* Internet Explorer */
*background: #FF7701;
background: #FF7701\0/;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="gradient-bg.png", sizingMethod="scale");
}
@media all and (min-width: 0px) {
    .gradient {
        /* Opera */
        background: #FF7701 url("gradient-bg.svg");
        /* Recent browsers */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top, left bottom,
            from(#FFAD26),
            to(#FF7701),
    color-stop(0.5, #FEA026),
    color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
    color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
    color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
    color-stop(0.5, #FF8B00)
        );
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
            top,
            #FFAD26,
            #FEA026 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FF8B00 50%,
    #FF7701
        );
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
            top,
            #FFAD26,
            #FEA026 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FF8B00 50%,
    #FF7701
        );
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
            top,
            #FFAD26,
            #FEA026 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FF8B00 50%,
    #FF7701
        );
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            top,
            #FFAD26,
            #FEA026 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FFFFFF 50%,
    #FF8B00 50%,
    #FF7701
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do give this a check in iOS but it ought to work:

```
background: #ffad26; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffad26 0%, #fea026 50%, #ff8b00 51%, #ff7701 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffad26), color-stop(50%,#fea026), color-stop(51%,#ff8b00), color-stop(100%,#ff7701)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffad26 0%,#fea026 50%,#ff8b00 51%,#ff7701 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffad26 0%,#fea026 50%,#ff8b00 51%,#ff7701 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffad26 0%,#fea026 50%,#ff8b00 51%,#ff7701 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffad26 0%,#fea026 50%,#ff8b00 51%,#ff7701 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffad26', endColorstr='#ff7701',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I'd also recommend looking into a pre-processor like SASS which will generate a lot of these things for you.

**Alternative 1**

As an alternative, you could try using an inset box shadow. It's not exact, and it has it's limitations but it's just an option :)

```
background-color:#FF8B00;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

**Alternative 2**

If you know the height, either use the box shadow above or just use a background image. That way you'll get cross-browser support without the mess that is a hundred prefixed CSS properties like above :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an ipad myself so a friend is testing for me with both an ipad mini and a ipad 3. On the mini it works, but not on the ipad 3... I have applied your code now, could you test for me if it works for you? Check: http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/

Comment: see my reply above. It doesn't work as it's supposed too. I'd like to reward you with the bounty, but therefore we have to fix this first :)

Comment: @Forza Try specifying a height on your element. Try height:100%, for example. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure there is a CSS-only solution other that what I've written above. If that doesn't work, I'd use an image and tile it using background-repeat: repeat-y;

Comment: That image worked lol. Crap CSS working different in every browser... Good old image fixed it :) Thx Rob!

Comment: @Forza its not fair to blame this on CSS. Each browser dictates how much of css it will support and how well. I am sure you wouldnt blame the W3C for the troubles you used to have on IE.

Answer (score 66):

In mobile Safari at least, you can't use the keyword `transparent`, you have to use `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` instead.

This is described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/Gradients/Gradient.html

As you can see, even in Apple's own official document, `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` is used instead of `transparent`.

Comment: Thank you this solves one of the issues I've been having

Comment: This works (at least on iOS 8) and is the simplest solution, by far.

Comment: Thank you. This works for me, fading from transparent to a solid color and back again: `linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255, 249, 240, 0), rgba(255, 249, 240, 1), rgba(255, 249, 240, 0))`. It looks great on all devices now!

Comment: This just helped me too, thanks!  It's only gradients that have trouble with the `transparent` keyword on iOS, or do other properties require rgba too?

Comment: OP didn't use `transparent`... Am I missing something?

Comment: This solved a problem I had at work. You can reproduce the behavior using this codepen if you've got mobile iOS (Tested on iPad 10.3.3)

https://codepen.io/phebert/pen/MGyqeo

Comment: This is amazingly annoying behavior.  Does Apple provide any reason they don't respect `transparent` as a color in gradient?  Literally no other browser has the same limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Working DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/akRHX/

And its iPhone screenshot...

[image]

add your css class to the element.

## HTML

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

       <div class="ui-grid-a">
           <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar gradient" style="height:200px">Block A</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar gradient" style="height:200px">Block B</div>
       </div>

</div><!-- /grid-a -->

    </div><!-- /content -->


</div><!-- /page -->
```

## CSS

```
.gradient {
    /* Legacy browsers */
    background: #FF7701 url("gradient-bg.png") repeat-x top;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /* Internet Explorer */
    *background: #FF7701;
    background: #FF7701\0/;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="gradient-bg.png", sizingMethod="scale");
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 0px) {
        .gradient {
            /* Opera */
            background: #FF7701 url("gradient-bg.svg");
            /* Recent browsers */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
                linear,
                left top, left bottom,
                from(#FFAD26),
                to(#FF7701),
        color-stop(0.5, #FEA026),
        color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
        color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
        color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF),
        color-stop(0.5, #FF8B00)
            );
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #FFAD26,
                #FEA026 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FF8B00 50%,
        #FF7701
            );
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #FFAD26,
                #FEA026 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FF8B00 50%,
        #FF7701
            );
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #FFAD26,
                #FEA026 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FF8B00 50%,
        #FF7701
            );
            background-image: linear-gradient(
                top,
                #FFAD26,
                #FEA026 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FFFFFF 50%,
        #FF8B00 50%,
        #FF7701
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the following worked and this worked for me in desktop browser, android and ios:-

```
display: list-item;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #2b4bff, #1b681f);
background-clip: text;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

1. I was using display:flex and that did not work and I had to change
   to list-item.
2. Color I was using 'transparent' and now I am using
   rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)

Some helpful notes:
The property background-clip: text; only works in Safari when applied directly to the element you want styled. You cannot apply it to a parent element and style all children at once. (This does work in Chrome and Firefox)
[enter link description here](https://www.twobrainy.com/posts/adventures-with-background-clip-and-flex-in-safari/)

Comment: color rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) instead of transparent fixed the problem for me!