# Cross-browser css for background image with a linear gradient

Tags: html, ios, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have some css to place a background image within a div with a linear gradient like so:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0,.15)), url(image.jpg);
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Yet nothing shows at all on iPad or iPhone. I've looked at a few other questions ([Background image not showing on iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999660/background-image-not-showing-on-ipad-and-iphone), [CSS gradient not working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816648/css-gradient-not-working-on-ios)) but haven't successfully been able to put it together.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to use an auto prefixer via javascript , most of the time more efficient than to write dozens of rules (that will come obsolete quiet soon) instead a few clear and clean ones in your style sheet

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you are not using the correct prefix for the browser.  While you are using a prefix on the background-size, linear-gradient also requires a prefix for different browsers.  You can check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) tips for CSS Gradients and you can also check out the [Safari Developer's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html) on using CSS gradients.  Here is a quick example of the different prefixes for linear-gradient.

```
  -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  -o-linear-gradient(red, green, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  -moz-linear-gradient(red, green, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   linear-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Standard syntax */
```